# How do I setup a wordpress category to run at the same level as the blog root cateogry?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed at **domain.tld/members**
This is going to be a protected area of the site.

I have a front end for signup and such that is static running at the root **domain.tld/**

I want to run a public blog at **domain.tld/blog/** but it will really just be a category of the main wordpress install that is located at **domain.tld/members/blog**

Is there a way to make that one category run at that upper level so that I can protect the entire **members** directory and keep the **blog** category public and all running off the same install?

Comment: I don't think wordpress will support that by default but you should be able to do it with .htaccess.

Comment: Yea I kinda figured that.. but I would think I wasnt' the first guy to have this idea? I'm using amember for protection if that means anything. But ideally I'd like to get the blog category up a level in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your blog should be public and Your members directory should be seen by only members.

1. Just install this plugin. 
   http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content/ It will work like a charm.
2. I think you are creating some social network. If so, you can use "buddypress".
   http://buddypress.org/

Comment: I don't need help protecting the content. I need to get the category to resolve at the same level as the install as I mentioned.

Comment: Jesse, Create a custom page,point that url to domain.tld/members/blog.